# How to make JUnit tests with Tomcat 8 + JSF 2.2?

Tags: model-view-controller, junit, jsf-2.2, tomcat8, arquillian-drone

I would like to know how to make `JUnit tests` with `Tomcat 8 + JSF 2.2`?
What kind of things can I test with `JUnit`? the `view`?, the `model`?, the `control`?

Do I have to make use of another tool with JUnit in order to make test cases?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in every program - with JUnit-Tests you are able to test units/components/classes. To test the combination of your classes with the JSF framework (if these tests really are needed) I would use GUI (integration-)tests with Selenium or other tools to simulate the use of the web application.